# Jeopardy questions in Excel or other database format?

Tags: database

A lot of sites post Jeopardy questions.  But does anyone know if there are Jeopardy questions (and answers, categories) available in an computer application consumable format like in a database or Excel or CSV file?  Assume this data will be fed into a Jeopardy online game.

Comment: It would seem to me that Jeopardy questions would be the copyrighted property of the show, and not subject to some sort of open source licensing scheme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some searching, and I can't find any in a consumable format. What I would suggest doing is programatically creating a list from this site: http://www.j-archive.com/listseasons.php

You can do something like this, and it shouldn't be too difficult:

```
// Pseudocode for compiling a list of Jeopardy questions/answers
questions = array();
answers = array();
for (i = first_game_id; i <= last_game_id; i++) {
  if (gameIdExistsOnSite(i)) {
    html = retrievePageHTMLForGameId(i);
    divs = getQuestionDivsFromHTML(html);
    foreach (divs as div) {
      questions[] = getQuestionFromDiv(div);
      answers[] = getAnswerFromDiv(div);
    }
  }
}

csv = convertToCSV(questions, answers);
```

Answer (score 2):

I know that this question is rather old, but for the newcomers and Google searchers:

I have written a small script in Python that parses questions from the [J! Archive](http://j-archive.com/) website and dumps them into a SQLite database. [See it on GitHub.](https://github.com/whymarrh/jeopardy-parser)