# How to extract Jeopardy Questions & Answers from a website?

Tags: python

Here is the (mess) of a script I have thus far. http://pastebin.com/prpdJXsq

```
#Jeopardy!
#Goal is to create a list of lists ie.
#[[Category 1, Question 1, Answer 1], [Category 1, Question 2, Answer 2]]
#First iteration will just be Q


import urllib.request, re

Question = []

first_game_id = 3458
last_game_id = 3713

for gameid in range(first_game_id, last_game_id):
    webpageid = "http://www.j-archive.com/showgame.php?game_id=" + str(gameid)
    temp=urllib.request.urlopen(webpageid)
    webpage=temp.read()
    temp.close()
    for line in webpage:
        if question != None:
            Question.append(question)
print(Question)

#wrong.  ??? = figure out which re to insert?

question = re.match('clue_text\"></td>')
answer= re.match'correct_response&quot;&gt;???&'


#trying to use re match and compile to match the string and output tuple?
import urllib.request, re
webpageid = "http://www.j-archive.com/showgame.php?game_id=" + str(3713)
temp=urllib.request.urlopen(webpageid)
webpage=temp.read()
temp.close()

question=re.compile(r'clue_text">*?</td>')

Question = []
##
##for line in webpage:
##    print(line)
##
##    if question.match(line) != None:
##        Question.append(question)
##
##print(Question)
```

I'm a novice (at best) trying to write a python script to extract every Jeopardy question/answer from this awesome website:  http://www.j-archive.com/showseason.php?season=27

My general approach was to follow the psuedo code I found here in response to a similar question but this is as far as I have gotten: [Jeopardy questions in Excel or other database format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025323/jeopardy-questions-in-excel-or-other-database-format)

Any constructive criticism or outright jeering would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please list the specific things you're having trouble with as well as posting the code and linking to what you're trying to do.

Comment: +1 for the sheer randomness of what you are trying to achieve

Comment: As a sidenote, instead of downloading each webpage in turn using `urllib`, this would be a good occasion to use the `wget` utility to download the entire website to disk. Then you can process the data at the speed of your hard disk (fast!) instead of the speed of your internet connection (slow.)

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend using [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/), and take advantage of it's [XPath support](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html):

```
import lxml.html

doc = lxml.html.parse('http://www.j-archive.com/showgame.php?game_id=1')
# get all td's with class="clue_text", these are the clues
clues = doc.xpath('//td[@class="clue_text"]')
# create a dict of clue_id, clue_text
clues_by_id = dict((x.attrib['id'], x.text) for x in clues)
```